# Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a little java project that is going to insert the tennis' players data into the database. However, I am getting this error:

```
2023-02-25T15:52:06.800-05:00 ERROR 16196 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4d7e1886
```

Which leads to this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong with the project?
My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.datajek</groupId>
    <artifactId>tennis-player-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tennis-player-rest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Player.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String nationality;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date birthDate;

    private int titles;

    public Player() {

    }

    public Player(String name, String nationality, Date birthDate, int titles) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public int getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

    public void setTitles(int titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nPlayer [id= " + id + ", name= " + name + ", nationality= " + nationality + ", birthDate= " + birthDate
                + ", titles= " + titles + "]";
    }
}
```

full error message:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-02-25T16:03:29.326-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] i.d.t.TennisPlayerRestApplication        : Starting TennisPlayerRestApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 21604 (C:\Users\roman\IdeaProjects\tennis-player-rest\target\classes started by roman in C:\Users\roman\IdeaProjects\tennis-player-rest)
2023-02-25T16:03:29.329-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] i.d.t.TennisPlayerRestApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-25T16:03:29.808-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-02-25T16:03:29.854-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 37 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-02-25T16:03:30.042-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-02-25T16:03:30.063-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2023-02-25T16:03:30.303-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-25T16:03:30.311-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-25T16:03:30.312-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-25T16:03:30.392-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-25T16:03:30.393-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1021 ms
2023-02-25T16:03:30.444-05:00 ERROR 21604 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4d7e1886
2023-02-25T16:03:30.445-05:00  WARN 21604 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
2023-02-25T16:03:30.447-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-02-25T16:03:30.457-05:00  INFO 21604 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-25T16:03:30.470-05:00 ERROR 21604 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at io.datajek.tennisplayerrest.TennisPlayerRestApplication.main(TennisPlayerRestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.h2.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:488) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:479) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:373) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

1)I tried adding different dependencies to the pom.xml to figure out if that was a problem, but that did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error suggests, it looks like you’re missing the H2 dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! it now says: 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'playerRepository' defined in io.datajek.tennisplayerrest.PlayerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class io.datajek.tennisplayerrest.Player`


Do you know what could be a problem?

Comment: “Not a managed type” suggests that perhaps you haven’t defined `Player` with the `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: Disregard that, I just saw in your OP that it has the annotation. I would suggest adding the `@Table` annotation and see if that fixes it.